# phpinfo shows allow_url_fopen is Off. It is On in php.ini

Tags: php, php-ini

I'm trying to run a php website with nginx using php8.1 and php8.1-fpm, in a Ubuntu 20.04 vps.

phpinfo reports that the config file in use is: /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini

It also reports that allow_url_fopen is Off (both Local Value and Master Value).
Examining /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini shows:

`allow_url_fopen = On`

I suppose that's the default setting. But I need this value to reflect in phpinfo and I can't get that to work.

I've tried changing the value, restarting nginx and fpm, changing it back and restarting again, but nothing works. Feels like phpinfo is getting its values elsewhere. I've checked all files in /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d (the config folder reported by phpinfo) and there is no allow_url_fopen in any of those.

How do I get allow_url_fopen to be On?

Comment: Why do you need that data in phpinfo to be correct? Does this influence any functionality in your application?

Comment: Please type `php --ini` and see, if your installation is loading other ini-files as well. If so (especially with cpanel) there might be a chance, that the setting is disabled in an additional ini-file and therefore overrides your (manual) setting.

Comment: @NicoHaase yes the application needs allow_url_fopen to be On to work

Comment: @LokendraSinghPanwar php --ini shows the cli counterparts to my fpm configs. In this case /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini also shows allow_url_fopen = On. Also not using cpanel or similar software

Answer (score 0):

1. Type “php --ini” command to find the location of the PHP configuration file.
   [image]

On the above server, you can see that the PHP configuration file is in location “/usr/local/lib/php.ini”

2. Edit the php.ini file to enable allow_url_fopen.

   root@server [~]# vi /usr/local/lib/php.ini
   allow_url_fopen = On
3. Change the line “allow_url_fopen = Off” to “allow_url_fopen = On”
4. Save the php.ini file after changing allow_url_fopen to On.
5. Restart the apache service after enabling allow_url_fopen.

Now, allow_url_fopen is enabled globally for all domains on your Server. allow_url_include = On

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is already set to `On` according to OP. Using nginx, not Apache

Comment: yes allow_url_fopen is already set to On

Answer (score 0):

On some systems there's a file `/etc/php.d/security.ini` or `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/99-security.conf` in which `allow_url_fopen` is turned of. If present it overrides the settings in `php.ini` system wide.

Unfortunately this file isn't listed by `php_ini_scanned_files()`.

Comment: Unfortunately both files aren't present in my system. Checked all files In /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d and there is no mention of allow_url_fopen